# Comparison between 2g and 3g in terms of PHYSICAL layer

Tags: wireless, mobile, telephony

I am doing a little research about comparison between 2g and 3g wireless communication technologies in terms of physical OSI layer. I want to focus especially coding differences. However, I couldn't be sure which coding methods are subjects for physical layer. Source coding, channel coding and line coding are coding techniques that I can find by now. Recently, I figured out that channel coding is in link layer (2. layer). My question is which topics I have to focus on.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For layer 1 (Physical) you may compare (if you compare only the radio interface):

- Electromagnetic spectrum (radio frequencies)
- Channel width
- Spectral efficiency
- Signal levels
- Modulation
- Antennas, feeders, power of transmitters, sensitivity of receivers and other parameters

And these maybe are on the border between layer 1 and 2 :

- channel coding
- media access method